# How to Copy List item to Another list using sharepoint designer 2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have used this workflow action in past with designer 2007, 2010, but 2013 sharepoint designer has Copy List Item workflow action missing. i am building a workflow in 2013 deisnger, now i want to utilize similar feature in my workflow. 
If the field status is set to Expired, copy that item and move it over to Archived list item and delete that item .

Is there any workaround of achieving this in SharePoint designer 2013 workflow.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You don't have the copy item in the 2013 workflow engine, indeed. This doesn't mean you can't do it in SharePoint 2013 - you just need to choose the 2010 platform, you have a dropdown when you create the workflow and the default is 2013 but you can change it.

2013 lost some actions as it's a platform that sits outside of SharePoint (WAW - Windows Azure Workflow) and doesn't have direct access to the list items. This makes it more scalable as it can run on a separate server and it has loops and stages so it's a much more powerful workflow system than WWF3 but you do lose some functionality, you can't edit permissions for instance.

You can also do this on the 2013 platform if you need it as part of something more complex that involves loops but you need to do it through coordination action i.e. you call a 2010 workflow within the 2013 one.

Answer (score 0):

This action is not aviabale for sharepoint 2013 designer.

- Copy List Item (SharePoint Designer 2013 supports only the document-copying action.)

Check this Article[Discontinued features in SharePoint Designer 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj728659(v=office.15).aspx#WhatsChangedSharePointDesigner2013_DiscontinuedFeatures)

Comment: Is there any workarounds for that feature?

Comment: i dont think so, only option is use 2010 workflow...also check this http://www.kumpulansoalun.com/read/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-copy-list-item/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from SharePoint Designer, but it's not straight forward.  You can use the the REST services to create the item.  I pulled the below from the following URL:

http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-sharepoint-rest-services-from.html

Create 3 dictionary items and use those to create your REST query.

```
Dictionary Item

Accept : application/json; odata=verbose 

Content-Type : application/json; odata=verbose 


Dictionary Item

metadata : SP.Data.WorkflowItemsListItem. 


Dictionary Item

parameters: _metadata | workflow values and variables | metadata



Call your HTTP endpoint _api/web/lists/getbytitle('<listname>')/items using the above values to creat your item.
```

To copy an items you would just populate your metadata variable with data from the existing item where you are running the workflow.  Depending on where your list lives you could bump up against permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an item from one list to another on the same site the option in SPD 2010 is to Copy Item but the option in SPD 2013 is to Create List Item. This function you will need to Map each field you want from the 1 list to the other but I found it very easy to complete.