# Is it possible to design a workflow that duplicates list items to a Main Site from a Subsite?

Tags: 2013, workflow, sub-site

I am trying to build a workflow that originates on the creation of a post in a Sub-site, then it duplicates the fields from that post (Published, Title, Body) to a list on my main site.  My question is twofold:

1. Can I have my workflow crawl up the chain, per se, to the Main site?
2. Is there a stock action in workflows to create a new list item?  Basically, is the workflow I want to create even possible?  I haven't seen anything that allows the duplication of list fields before.

My SharePoint 2013 site is set up as follows:

```
sharepoint.company.com
|-Destination List
|-sharepoint.company.com/ccn
  |-Origin List
```

Comment: What I would suggest is expose the list or listitems in a content query webpart--not duplicate it in another list

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123017/how-to-copy-list-item-to-another-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow

Also you may want to have a look at [Cross Site Publishing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/02/19/an-introduction-to-cross-site-publishing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box not available.

You can try `Copy Item Extended` Activity available in code plex

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Thanks Amal, 
I'm seeing a lot of comments that that extension doesn't work with SP2013, which is what I'm on

Comment: You can look around for similar custom activities. OOB it is not available.